# Why is OAuth a valid authentication process?

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, credentials

I was interested in OAuth authentication.
Before, I had done JSON Web Token authorization, where one basically sends user registration credentials to a webserver that I implemented in Node.js, and then kind of "incorporate" the user credentials into a JWT after having encrypted the password and the credentials. The encrypted password is saved with some other user information and the token (depends on the implementation) for the new registered user in some backend database (e.g MongoDB).

Now, I was wondering how that "authentication" with a new user in OAuth happens. I was just wondering, because I could simply do a login with an existing google account and then I was "authenticated".

But the thing is, that looks more like a "guest account" rather than a real user registration. 
I mean shouldn't there be some backend-part where user information is stored, and then you can do something like assign different roles to users to grant or restrict access to different parts of your page, or is the complete backend part a part of the configuration when you log into you OAuth account?

In JWT, that information is encoded into the JWT, and you can either verify e.g user roles encrypted into the token on the client-side or the server API backend side where you decrypt the token again and check if some role is allowed or not... How is that whole thing handled with OAuth? Because I don't see the connecting parts in the OAuth authentication, I have some kind of "guest account" but my user is in no way specified for my specific application or some use-case... or is this all handled on the OAuth page on their part?

Answer (score 1):

Repeat after me:
[OAuth is NOT an Authentication Protocol.](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20NOT%20an%20Authentication%20protocol)
OAuth 2.0 is NOT an Authentication protocol. (But you could build one on top of OAuth 2.0 as is done with OpenID Connect

OAuth 2.0 is NOT an Authorization protocol.

OAuth 2.0 is often called an authorization protocol, even the RFC 6749 is called "The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework". However, OAuth 2.0 is a delegation protocol.

What is delegated is a subset of the a user’s authorization. OAuth 2.0 does not even perform the Authorization but rather provides a protocol where a OAuth Client can request that a user delegate some of their authority. The user can then approve, or deny, the request, and the OAuth Client can then act on it with the results of that approval.

Comment: ok so if I understand correctly if a request is approved, OAuth 2.0 then does sort of delegate the user-credentials or login information to another url or web-page where it is verified more specifically in a protocol way that involves a backend-server with authentication handling, user registration, creation and sending of a token, etc.. ?